# Drupal created timestamp in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-6

So when user are created in drupal website it creates a table row in SQL database, everybody knows that, but there is column `created` witch stands for create date. It contains `int` type, something like this `1341319209`. I checked, it isn't the milliseconds from 01.01.1970.
The question is how can I convert it to normal date format using php or SQL Query? I tried to find how drupal does that, bet no success. Can someone please help. Write some code or give me a clue. :) Thanks.

Comment: _I checked, it isn't the milliseconds from 01.01.1970_. Nope. it's the number of _seconds_ since 01.01.1970. Treat it like you would any UNIX timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
MAKETIME( seconds / (60*60),
          seconds / 60,
          seconds % 60 )
```

or you may also try to use  **[FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)**

```
SELECT
  from_unixtime(timestamp) 
FROM 
  your_table
```

Comment: OK, I use `from_unixtime()` can i format it how I want for example DD.MM.YYYY because it have mm.HH.SS too but I dont need them. Is it posible?

Comment: @veiss:- You are welcome. You may try this to remove the hour content:- SELECT DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME( time ) , '%d/%m/%y )